# Merge PDF's or convert to PDF using Foxit Reader 9.7 or CutePDF Writer

Tags: vba, pdf, outlook, foxit-reader, pdfmerger

I'm trying to both merge multiple PDF's into one file, and also converting other file types to PDF through the VBA environment. 
It seem's work has done away with Adobe Acrobat. CutePDF Professional uses CutePDF Writer and also we have Foxit Reader 9.7 (Not Phantom).

I read that CutePDF Writer is non programmatic and same with Foxit unless its upgraded to Phantom.

Is this correct to assume I'm out of luck here now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both apps can convert other file types to PDF using a "virtual printer". Basically you select the "Print" function in any other application, select that virtual printer, and instead of a piece of paper, it spits out a PDF file saved on your computer.

Note that Foxit Reader 10.0 removed this functionality.

Comment: My bad, I failed to mention that I'm trying to do this process through the VBA environment.